# Jquery Ajax Callback not working in proper order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, callback

I have a piece of code I want to run after all the ajax is completed. 
The function I wish to run is:

```
function autoContinueCart(){
   $('.nextSection a:visible').click();
}
```

This click event runs validating script and moves to next section. Heres the main ajax.

```
$('#SubmitLoginOpc').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:authenticationUrl,
            async:false,
            cache:false,
            dataType:"json",
            data:'SubmitLogin=true&ajax=true&email=' + encodeURIComponent($('#login_email').val()) + '&passwd=' + encodeURIComponent($('#login_passwd').val()) + '&token=' + static_token,
            success:function (jsonData) {
                if (jsonData.hasError) {
                    //error stuff
                }
                else {
                    // update token
                    static_token = jsonData.token;

                    $('#dlv_label, #new_label').removeClass('new-l').addClass('logged-l'); // change label on delivery address section

                    updateNewAccountToAddressBlock();

                    // RESET ERROR(S) MESSAGE(S)
                    $('#opc_account_errors').html('').hide();
                    $('#opc_account_errors_invoice').html('').hide();
                    //It doesnt work here
                    //autoContinueCart();
                }

            },
           //doesnt work here
           // complete:autoContinueCart
        });
        return false;
    });
```

I have put this function call in the success part, which I thought would work since it is synchronous.  I also put it as complete and in .done function after the ajax call and it still runs before all the inside code is complete.  The function `updateNewAccountToAddressBlock();` basically makes another jquery ajax request with this type `async:true`, and returns json that is then used in about 10 functions or sub functions in the success call. One of these uses this data to fill out all the fields of a form.  My function I am trying to call at the end is supposed to validate the info that is being populated.  But no matter what I try, the validation is failing because the autoContineCart is being run before the fields are being populated.  I also tried to use a callback like `updateNewAccountToAddressBlock(updateAddressSelection);` and then checked callback function inside of that and it also didnt work.  Anyone have an idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Using `async:false` is not a solution, you're just making the problem worse. Look into jQuery deferred, and promise object.

Comment: So since something is "populating the fields", is there a way to know when that is finished? hook your method in there?

Comment: Why don't you try to use 'ajaxStop' global event handler to call autoContineCart method. But it will be triggered only if there are no Ajax requests are being processed.

Answer (score 0):

Since your call is already asynchronous, is it possible to move the processing code out of the ajax callback function? This would ensure that all of the ajax portion is complete before moving on to the processing piece.

Example:

```
$('#SubmitLoginOpc').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:authenticationUrl,
        async:false,
        cache:false,
        dataType:"json",
        data:'SubmitLogin=true&ajax=true&email=' + encodeURIComponent($('#login_email').val()) + '&passwd=' + encodeURIComponent($('#login_passwd').val()) + '&token=' + static_token
        },
        success: function(jsonData) {
            $('#SubmitLoginOpc').data("some_key",jsonData);
        }
       //doesnt work here
       // complete:autoContinueCart
    });
    jsonData = $('#SubmitLoginOpc').data("some_key");
    if (jsonData.hasError) {
        //error stuff
    }
    else {
        // update token
        static_token = jsonData.token;
        $('#dlv_label, #new_label').removeClass('new-l').addClass('logged-l'); // change label on delivery address section

        updateNewAccountToAddressBlock();
        // RESET ERROR(S) MESSAGE(S)
        $('#opc_account_errors').html('').hide();
        $('#opc_account_errors_invoice').html('').hide();
        //It doesnt work here
        //autoContinueCart();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I still get the same issue because I need updateNewAccountToAddressBlock(); to finish before autoContinueCart(); runs

Answer (score 0):

As the poster above said, Perhaps you could move some of the other ajax functions to run from the same js file, or move some of the Php functions to be run at the same time as the first call.

Ideally you shouldn't have to do another ajax request, because the php/whatever already has the info it needs from the client side. You should be able to send that data to other php/whatever  scripts.

If you do need to do another ajax call, perhaps having the user wait a mandatory second, before you run the ajax call.

for instance:

```
$ajax.done(
// code
 if (success)
{
   setTimeout('foo', 5000);
$('#spinner').show();
}

function foo()
{
$('#spinner').hide();
//second ajax request
}
```

Comment: I have this as a temporary workaround but the issues are: it takes 5 seconds to continue, and if someone hits the button that is visible it runs that code twice which is not what I want.